# WinNMP upgrade MariaDB to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I would like to change **MariaDB** to **MySQL** in my WinNMP Installation but I was not able to find any answers to solve that problem. It was no problem to fix that in XAMPP... Does someone has a clue or hint?

Comment: Not according to the WinNMP website. But there's nothing stopping you from installing MySQL separately.

Comment: Thank you. Its just a matter of portability that's beeing lost when installing mysql on my OS seperated...